# Difference between IIS reset and IIS service restart?

Tags: iis

What is the difference between these?

1. Restart IIS via Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Use the IISReset.exe tool.
3. Restart the IIS services via services.msc.

Comment: There is not enough documentation on that. 1 and 2 should be equivalent, but 3 is uncertain, as the previous two might perform service restart in a special order (which your manual restart might not follow).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these 3 options have the same effect.

But we recommend to go for Option1 and Option3. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732317(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

"Use the IISReset.exe tool" simple and user can still use it. But actually it is not supported anymore. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd364308(v=ws.10)).